# Python create folder next to .exe

Tags: python, path, directory, exe, vizard

I am using Vizard to create an .exe file off a python script. I need this script to create a folder which resides next to the .exe file

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    logging.warning('Application is exe')
    loggingPath = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    logging.warning(os.getcwd())
elif __file__:
    loggingPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    logging.warning('Application is script')
    logging.warning(os.getcwd())

if not os.path.exists(loggingFolder):
    logging.warning('Directory not existing... creating..')
    os.makedirs(loggingFolder)
```

works fine when I execute from the IDE, but in an exe file it throws data in the Appdata Folder in Windows/Users/Temp/randomfoldername.

Also, I always Application is script, even when its packed into exe.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What output do you get when running this?

Comment: Both when executing it from the ide and as executable, what is the output?

Comment: When I execute from IDE:
 WARNING:root:Application is script
 WARNING:root:G:\WakefulRest
 WARNING:root:G:\WakefulRest

 I know it says warning because I use loglevel warning, G is the usb drive. 

From the exe: 
The same output, but with a path to my user folder in windows.

Answer (score 1):

The sys module does not have any attribute `frozen`, which results in the first if statement always returning `False`.

`sys.executable` will give the path to the python interpreter binary, ie. for Windows the path of your `python.exe` file, which I cannot see why you would need for this.

If what you want is to ensure that the file running is a `.exe` file, then make a folder next to it, it may be simpler to just check if the filename ends with `.exe`?

```
if __file__.endswith('.exe'):
    loggingFolder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'foldername')
    if not os.path.exists(loggingFolder):
        os.makedirs(loggingFolder)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to create a folder at runtime, then another (possibly easier) method is to run your vizard program from within a batch file and create the folder first in the batch file

e.g. `create run_viz_prog.bat` with content like this :-

```
mkdir new_folder
my_viz_prog.exe
```